# Can't access my node in k8s via browser (with service & deployment)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

There is the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-task-tracker-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-task-tracker
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-task-tracker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: shaikezam/task-tracker:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

This is the service (NodePort):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-task-tracker-service
  labels:
    app: my-task-tracker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8085
      nodePort: 30001
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-task-tracker
```

Now, I try to access localhost:8085 or localhost:30001, and nothing happened.

I'm running using K8S in docker desktop.

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1` and this is not usually the ip assigned to nodes in K8s cluster. Take a look at what `kubectl get nodes -o wide` shows as the node's ip.

Comment: @AliTou I have internal-ip which also give me 404, and external-ip is <none>

Comment: Target port should be 8080 in service yaml if that is what your container runs on as per your deployment yaml file.

Comment: @TarunKhosla ok, after I changed the targetPort from 8085 to 8080 it worked, I cant have the pod listen to 8080 and the service listen to 8085?

Comment: `port` exposes the Kubernetes service on the specified port within the cluster. Other pods within the cluster can communicate with this server on the specified port.
`TargetPort` is the port on which the service will send requests to, that your pod will be listening on. Your application in the container will need to be listening on this port also.
`NodePort` exposes a service externally to the cluster by means of the target nodes IP address and the NodePort. NodePort is the default setting if the port field is not specified. You should be able to use your application on Nodeport as well.

Comment: In your case target port should be 8080 that is what is imporatnt for app to run , you can listen to your app on port 8085 within your cluster by changing the `port` field in the yaml.

Comment: @TarunKhosla how would you edit the svc.yaml file so that it will send the request to 8080 (pod port) and listen to 8085 (this is the exposed port)?

Answer (score 0):

Target port should be `8080` in service yaml if that is what your container runs on as per your deployment yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-task-tracker-service
  labels:
    app: my-task-tracker
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30001
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-task-tracker
```

=======

`port` exposes the Kubernetes service on the specified port within the cluster. Other pods within the cluster can communicate with this server on the specified port.

`TargetPort` is the port on which the service will send requests to, that your pod will be listening on. Your application in the container will need to be listening on this port also.

`NodePort` exposes a service externally to the cluster by means of the target nodes IP address and the NodePort. NodePort is the default setting if the port field is not specified. You should be able to use your application on Nodeport as well.

In your case target port should be 8080 that is what is important for app to run ,you can listen to your app on port 8085 within your cluster by changing the port field in the yaml and externally by changing the Nodeport.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work ether, after the port & targetPort both 8080

Comment: how did you access after changing ?

Comment: It's seems because of the cache while I access it through the docker container